# Extract data in linux/unix

Tags: linux, sed, awk, grep

I have input data which I want to parse and extract values using awk/grep/sed:

```
group-2 9 10 text color=black,from=ABCB11,fromid=4,order=2,thickness=3,to=ACE,toid=11,use=1,z=1
group-3 0 1 text color=black,from=ABCB11,fromid=4,order=2,thickness=3,to=ACE,toid=11,use=1,z=1
group-2 28 29 text color=black,from=ABCB11,fromid=4,order=2,thickness=3,to=CHRM1,toid=114,use=1,z=1
group-5 0 1 text color=black,from=ABCB11,fromid=4,order=2,thickness=3,to=CHRM1,toid=114,use=1,z=1
group-2 29 30 text color=black,from=ABCB11,fromid=4,order=2,thickness=3,to=CHRM2,toid=115,use=1,z=1
group-5 1 2 text color=black,from=ABCB11,fromid=4,order=2,thickness=3,to=CHRM2,toid=115,use=1,z=1
group-2 10 11 text color=black,from=ABCB11,fromid=4,order=2,thickness=3,to=DRD2,toid=158,use=1,z=1
group-3 1 2 text color=black,from=ABCB11,fromid=4,order=2,thickness=3,to=DRD2,toid=158,use=1,z=1
group-2 11 12 text color=black,from=ABCB11,fromid=4,order=2,thickness=3,to=EGF,toid=164,use=1,z=1
group-3 2 3 text color=black,from=ABCB11,fromid=4,order=2,thickness=3,to=EGF,toid=164,use=1,z=1
group-2 21 22 text color=black,from=ABCC8,fromid=5,order=2,thickness=3,to=ACE,toid=11,use=1,z=1
group-3 12 13 text color=black,from=ABCC8,fromid=5,order=2,thickness=3,to=ACE,toid=11,use=1,z=1
group-2 0 1 text color=black,from=ABCC8,fromid=5,order=2,thickness=3,to=ADRA1A,toid=21,use=1,z=1
group-1 0 1 text color=black,from=ABCC8,fromid=5,order=2,thickness=3,to=ADRA1A,toid=21,use=1,z=1
group-2 1 2 text color=black,from=ABCC8,fromid=5,order=2,thickness=3,to=ADRA1B,toid=22,use=1,z=1
group-1 1 2 text color=black,from=ABCC8,fromid=5,order=2,thickness=3,to=ADRA1B,toid=22,use=1,z=1
group-2 2 3 text color=black,from=ABCC8,fromid=5,order=2,thickness=3,to=ADRA1D,toid=23,use=1,z=1
group-1 2 3 text color=black,from=ABCC8,fromid=5,order=2,thickness=3,to=ADRA1D,toid=23,use=1,z=1
```

Basically,I want to take the distinct values in "from=" and its "fromid" and "to=" and its "toid=" which can be seen below as to how the output should be:

The desired output.has to be the values in "from=" and "to=" joined row wise.Since from=ABCB11 is present many times but I want only it once,so as the value in "to=" has to be once in the output.

Whatever is present as fromid or toid ,I want all rows to have fromid,after taking distinct values from both. The format of the output can be interpreted from below output:

```
ABCB11 = fromid=4,from=ABCB11
ABCC8 = fromid=5,from=ABCC8
ACE = fromid=11,from=ACE
CHRM1 = fromid=114,from=CHRM1
CHRM2 = fromid=115,from=CHRM2
DRD2 = fromid=158,from=DRD2
EGF = fromid=164,from=EGF
ADRA1A = fromid=21,from=ADRA1A
ADRA1B = fromid=22,from=ADRA1B
ADRA1D = fromid=23,from=ADRA1D
```

I want to have exactly the same output as above,but I have a new input file,which is below:

```
ABCB11  4   ACE 11
ABCB11  4   CHRM1   114
ABCB11  4   CHRM2   115
ABCB11  4   DRD2    158
ABCB11  4   EGF 164
ABCC8   5   ACE 11
ABCC8   5   ADRA1A  21
ABCC8   5   ADRA1B  22
ABCC8   5   ADRA1D  23
ABCC8   5   CHRM1   114
```

Taking all the unique genes and creating the output.

Comment: Why your `to=` in output is different with `to=` from input?

Comment: Its just the unique values that I want in my output.taking the unique of "from" and "to" and joining them row wise.

Comment: So can you correct your output to fit with input?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use an awk *associative array* indexed by the field whose uniqueness you are asserting e.g. for the unique values of the `to=` field (field `$6` when split on commas):

```
$ awk -F, '{split($6,s,"="); arr[s[2]]=s[2]" = "$7","$6;} END{for (id in arr) print arr[id]}' data.txt
EGF = toid=164,to=EGF
ADRA1A = toid=21,to=ADRA1A
ACE = toid=11,to=ACE
ADRA1B = toid=22,to=ADRA1B
ADRA1D = toid=23,to=ADRA1D
DRD2 = toid=158,to=DRD2
CHRM1 = toid=114,to=CHRM1
CHRM2 = toid=115,to=CHRM2
```

The expression for the unique `fromid` entries is the same but replacing fields `$6` and `$7` with `$2` and `$3`:

```
$ awk -F, '{split($2,s,"="); arr[s[2]]=s[2]" = "$3","$2;} END{for (id in arr) print arr[id]}' data.txt
ABCC8 = fromid=5,from=ABCC8
ABCB11 = fromid=4,from=ABCB11
```

If you want the output to contain both `toid` and `fromid` data, you can combine the expressions i.e.

```
awk -F, '{
split($2,s,"="); arr[s[2]]=s[2]" = "$3","$2;
split($6,s,"="); arr[s[2]]=s[2]" = "$7","$6;
} END{for (id in arr) print arr[id]}' data.txt
```

To change the labels (i.e. label all the fields in one table as `toid` even if they come from the `fromid` lines) probably the most natural way is to pipe the output through `sed` e.g.

```
$ awk -F, '{
split($2,s,"="); arr[s[2]]=s[2]" = "$3","$2;
split($6,s,"="); arr[s[2]]=s[2]" = "$7","$6;
} END{for (id in arr) print arr[id]}' data.txt | sed 's/from/to/g'
ABCC8 = toid=5,to=ABCC8
EGF = toid=164,to=EGF
ADRA1A = toid=21,to=ADRA1A
ACE = toid=11,to=ACE
ABCB11 = toid=4,to=ABCB11
ADRA1B = toid=22,to=ADRA1B
ADRA1D = toid=23,to=ADRA1D
DRD2 = toid=158,to=DRD2
CHRM1 = toid=114,to=CHRM1
CHRM2 = toid=115,to=CHRM2
```

You could make the `fromid <--> toid` substitutions inside `awk` but this method makes the intent clearer, I think. The other table can then be made just by changing the final `sed` expression to `sed 's/to/from/g'` instead.

Comment: It works great but I am not getting these two values ABCB11 = toid=4,to=ABCB11
ABCC8 = toid=5,to=ABCC8.

Comment: Can you clarify which field (or combination of fields) you want to test, and which you want to output? The expression I gave finds unique values of field $6 which is the `to=` field - it can be modified but I don't understand your requirements.

Comment: You do not have toid=4 and toid=5 in your question.

Comment: @steeldriver if you see the two outputs,irrespective of the from in input table,In the output I want distinct values present in "from" as well in my output.I have printed the exact two outputs that I want!I can do find and replace to get the other output,so even if I get one of them,it works for me.

Comment: @Ramesh I do not have toid=4 and toid=5 in my question,but I want my output like that.If you see the required output!!

Comment: Well if the outputs that you want don't actually come from the input file, it's not really a data extraction question, is it? You may as well just print or echo the required lines.

Comment: The output come from the input file,but those have to be extracted irrespective of fromid or toid  and taking only distinct values.I can not be more clear than that,after printing out the exact outputs I want from my inputs.

Comment: I have edited my answer - I hope this is now what you want

Comment: @steeldriver the last awk command gives the result!

Comment: @steeldriver Also,I have another input file,but the required output remains the same.Can I just put "\t" instead of "=" in the awk script?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the names are in a file called "filename.txt", You can try the following for the first table:

> cat filename.txt | awk -F "," '{ print $2 " = " $7 "," $6}' | sed -r 's/^.{5}//'

For the second table:

> cat filename.txt | awk -F "," '{ print $2 " = " $3 "," $6}' | sed -r 's/^.{5}//'

Good luck!

EDIT:
For the second table:

> cat filename.txt | awk -F "," '{ print $2 " = " $7 "," $6}' | sed  -r   's/^.{5}//' | sed  's/toid/fromid/'

EDIT 2:

> cat filename.txt | awk -F "," '{ print $2 " = " $7 "," $6}' | sed 's/^.....//'  | sed 's/toid/fromid/'

these are 5 dots.

Comment: The OP wants unique values. So, you can use uniq at the end of the commands to get the exact output as the OP needs.

Comment: [UUOC alert](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Cat_(Unix)&section=8#Useless_use_of_cat)

Comment: sed command after pipe throws error                               sed: illegal option -- r

Comment: It doesn't procedure output as the OP show.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were filtering for different columns. How about: cat filename.txt | awk -F "," '{ print $2 " = " $7 "," $6}' | sed -r 's/^.{5}//' | sed 's/toid/fromid/'

Comment: Again sed -r throws an error.What it is used for?I have checked online but have not found examples of this option.

Comment: equivalent to --regexp-extended. I used it to remove the 'fromid=' from the beginning. It is followed by a space.

Comment: Please check the edits, I will replace the -r with something less elegant but hopefully will work for you.