# Parse,Manipulate Data In linux/Unix

Tags: linux, sed, awk, grep

I want to have exactly the same output in this post([Extract data in linux/unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126139/extract-data-in-linux-unix)as) above,but I have a new input file,which is below:

```
ABCB11  4   ACE 11
ABCB11  4   CHRM1   114
ABCB11  4   CHRM2   115
ABCB11  4   DRD2    158
ABCB11  4   EGF 164
ABCC8   5   ACE 11
ABCC8   5   ADRA1A  21
ABCC8   5   ADRA1B  22
ABCC8   5   ADRA1D  23
ABCC8   5   CHRM1   114
```

Taking all the unique genes and creating the output.

I want all rows to have fromid,after taking distinct values from both. The exact output is what I want below:

```
ABCB11 = fromid=4,from=ABCB11
ABCC8 = fromid=5,from=ABCC8
ACE = fromid=11,from=ACE
CHRM1 = fromid=114,from=CHRM1
CHRM2 = fromid=115,from=CHRM2
DRD2 = fromid=158,from=DRD2
EGF = fromid=164,from=EGF
ADRA1A = fromid=21,from=ADRA1A
ADRA1B = fromid=22,from=ADRA1B
ADRA1D = fromid=23,from=ADRA1D
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming 4 columns, a two-pass solution

```
awk 'NR == FNR {if (s[$1]++ == 0)
{printf "%s = fromid=%s, from=%s\n", $1, $2, $1}; next};
!s[$3]++{printf "%s = fromid=%s, from=%s\n", $3, $4, $3}' file file
ABCB11 = fromid=4, from=ABCB11
ABCC8 = fromid=5, from=ABCC8
ACE = fromid=11, from=ACE
CHRM1 = fromid=114, from=CHRM1
CHRM2 = fromid=115, from=CHRM2
DRD2 = fromid=158, from=DRD2
EGF = fromid=164, from=EGF
ADRA1A = fromid=21, from=ADRA1A
ADRA1B = fromid=22, from=ADRA1B
ADRA1D = fromid=23, from=ADRA1D
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind the order of ouput:

```
$ awk '!($1 in a){a[$1] = $2}
       !($3 in a){a[$3] = $4}
       END {
           for(i in a) {
               print i" = fromid="a[i]",from="i
           }
       }' file
EGF = fromid=164,from=EGF
CHRM1 = fromid=114,from=CHRM1
CHRM2 = fromid=115,from=CHRM2
ACE = fromid=11,from=ACE
ADRA1A = fromid=21,from=ADRA1A
DRD2 = fromid=158,from=DRD2
ABCB11 = fromid=4,from=ABCB11
ADRA1B = fromid=22,from=ADRA1B
ABCC8 = fromid=5,from=ABCC8
ADRA1D = fromid=23,from=ADRA1D
```